# Is glass amorphous solid or supercooled liquid?

Tags: solid-state-chemistry

I've read that glass is a supercooled liquid. But lately I've came to know in a science info post that glass is amorphous solid. How? Please someone explain me.

Comment: Is the glass half-empty, or half-full?